# Query the relation using the result from the nested relation

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

here i have the code below that i want to filter my hotels and pick the lowest price room for each hotel :

```
 $city_id = $request->get('city_id');
            $stars = $request->get('grade_stars');
            $type_id = $request->get('accommodation_type_id');
            $from_date = $request->get('from_date');
            $to_date = $request->get('to_date');
            $data = Accommodation::with(['city','accommodationRoomsLimited.roomPricingHistorySearch' =>function($query) use($from_date,$to_date){
                $query->whereDate('from_date', '<=', $from_date);
                $query->whereDate('to_date', '>=', $to_date);
                }])
                ->whereIn('city_id',$city_id)
                ->whereIn('grade_stars',$stars)
                ->orWhere('accommodation_type_id',$type_id)
                ->paginate(10);
            return $data;
```

and here is my accommodation model :

```
    public function accommodationRoomsLimited()
{
    return $this->Hasmany(AccommodationRoom::class)->select('id', 'accommodation_id');
}
```

and in my accommodation room model :

```
  public function roomPricingHistorySearch()
{
    return $this->hasOne(RoomPricingHistory::class,'accommodation_room_id','id')->orderBy('sales_price','ASC');
}
```

and i have a table called room pricing history that keeps the log of room prices for each day  here is my output in api that i want to pick the 1 room with the lowest sales_price in room_pricing_history_search:

```
"accommodation_rooms_limited": [
        {
            "id": 4859,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 15741,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4859,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 50,

                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4860,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4990,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4860,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 1760000,

                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4861,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4991,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4861,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 2270000,

                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 4862,
            "accommodation_id": 47,
            "room_pricing_history_search": {
                "id": 4992,
                "accommodation_room_id": 4862,
                "net_price": null,
                "sales_price": 2780000,

                "created_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00",
                "updated_at": "2019-05-25 13:30:00"
            }
        }
    ]
},
```

Answer (score 1):

It might be simpler to start by selecting the rooms instead of the hotels and then group by the hotels.

You could use a [raw expression](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/queries#raw-expressions) to get the lowest room price:

`$raw = DB::raw('min(price) as min_price');`

And then select from the rooms table and group by the hotel id:

```
Room::join('hotels', 'hotels.id' ,'=', 'rooms.hotel_id')
   ->whereDate('rooms.from_date', '<=', $from_date)
   ->whereDate('rooms.to_date', '>=', $to_date)
   ->select('hotels.*', $raw)
   ->groupBy('hotels.id')
   ->get()
```

Jonathan Reinink's recent talk [Eloquent Performance Patterns](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=IBUXXErAtuk) might also be of interest to you. He talks about similar queries to yours and it looks like the pull request he talks about that will make queries like these easier has been [merged](https://laravel-news.com/eloquent-subquery-enhancements) in Laravel 6.0. So from Laravel 6.0 you should be able to do something like this:

```
return Hotel::addSelect(['lowest_price' => function ($query) {
    $query->select('price')
        ->from('rooms')
        ->whereColumn('hotel_id', 'hotels.id')
        ->orderBy('price', 'asc')
        ->limit(1);
}])->get();
```

Comment: that raw query trying to get price from hotel idk why but i have a model called prices that handles the prices for room in different days

Comment: If you post the relevant parts of your database schema I might be able to help more with your specific case. Had to assume what your tables look like.

Comment: check my edited question i added my real code to it and now you should be able to find db structure if its not clear yet tell me to paste the migration in question

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like you need to read up on `orderBy` and `take` in the Eloquent documentation.

Check the `Adding Additional Constraints` section:  in https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/eloquent#retrieving-models